# iOS Custom Views don't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uikit, custom-view

I'm developing an app (by a tutorial, but the tutorial is written for Swift and I'm learning Objective-C. tutorial [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1)

But I have a problem, I'm developing a Custom Controller (RatingController), which works when I only use one of this custom controller in a scene. The Custom controller source is here:

```
@implementation RatingController

//MARK: Properties
const int spacing = 5;
const int starCount = 5;
UIButton *ratingButtons[starCount];

-(void)setRating:(int)rating{
    _rating = rating;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

-(int)getRating{
    return _rating;
}

//MARK: Initialization
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        //load the images
        UIImage *filledStarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"filledStar"];
        UIImage *emptyStarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"emptyStar"];

        for (int i = 0; i < starCount; i++) {
            //create button
            UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]init];

            //set the images
            [button setImage:emptyStarImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setImage:filledStarImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [button setImage:filledStarImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected];

            //No additional highlight when switching state
            button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false;

            //hook up the method which should be executed when the user touches a button
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ratingButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

            //add the button the the ratingButton array
            ratingButtons[i] = button;

            //add the button to the view
            [self addSubview:button];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) layoutSubviews{
    //Set the button's width and height to the height of the frame.
    const int buttonSize = self.frame.size.height;    
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonSize, buttonSize);

    for(int i = 0; i < starCount; i++){
        buttonFrame.origin.x = (i * (buttonSize + spacing));
        ratingButtons[i].frame = buttonFrame;
    }

    [self updateButtonSelectionState];
}

-(CGSize) intrinsicContentSize{
    const int buttonSize = self.frame.size.height;
    const int width = (buttonSize * starCount) + (spacing * (starCount -1));

    return CGSizeMake(width, buttonSize);
}

//MARK: Button Action
-(void) updateButtonSelectionState{
    for(int i = 0; i < starCount; i++)
        ratingButtons[i].selected = i < _rating;
}

-(void) ratingButtonTapped:(UIButton *) button{
    for(int i = 0; i < starCount; i++){
        if(ratingButtons[i] == button){
            _rating = i + 1;
        }
    }
    [self updateButtonSelectionState];
}

@end
```

When I put 2 of those custom controllers in 1 scene I can only see the one which is added at the end (in a list only the last List item shows the custom controller)
I hope someone can help me.

Thank you very much already!

Comment: What do you mean by two controllers in one scene?  Are you using them in container views?

Comment: Like here: https://snag.gy/n0jK1h.jpg every list item should contain the stars

Comment: Could you post the code for your tableview datasource, e.g. cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: MealTableViewController.m http://pastebin.com/pduLAmeQ MealTableViewCell.h http://pastebin.com/YRRuHCjf MealTableViewCell.m http://pastebin.com/46kxGDfC  @JingJingTao Ask if you need any more code.

Comment: @GilianJ: try adding an NSLog in your `layoutSubviews` to display `_rating` and `self.frame` and see if it gives you correct values.

Comment: @jp2g I've printed those values, what I see is that the last Item in the array calls layoutSubviews twice instead of once. The _rating value is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit2:**

Changed the ratingButton array into a property and mutable array, this resolved the issue.

**Edit:**

Also check your buttons are being added to your ratingButtons array in your init and that the code in 'updateButtonSelectionState' in working correctly.

**Original:**

It's worth checking your 'rating' setter, set a break point and check that the correct value is being passed for the first two cells.

Also maybe download the complete example, it's in swift but at least it gives you something to compare against, good luck.

Comment: The ratingButtons array is filled, when I put a breakpoint at the ratingButtons[i].frame = buttonFrame; line I get this result: https://snag.gy/pCyxKE.jpg And the 'rating' setter works, only the last item in the mealsArray calls the layoutSubviews(); method twice in a row, isn't that weird?

Comment: I guess we expect layoutSubviews to be called three times. Obvious checks, your break point in your init is triggered three times, check the actually frames being set in layoutSubviews.

Comment: The initWithCoder executes 3 times.  The first time layoutSubViews is called all values in the buttonFrame.frame are 0.0 this is unexpected behaviour. The other call values are correct

Comment: Well we're getting somewhere, what are the values of buttonSize and spacing on the first call? If some expected values of 0, hard code them and see what happens.

Comment: When I print the values of the frame after: ratingButtons[i].frame = buttonFrame; I get this result (4 times) frame origin x:0.000000, y:0.000000, w:44.000000, h:44.000000, frame origin x:49.000000, y:0.000000, w:44.000000, h:44.000000, frame origin x:98.000000, y:0.000000, w:44.000000, h:44.000000, frame origin x:147.000000, y:0.000000, w:44.000000, h:44.000000, frame origin x:196.000000, y:0.000000, w:44.000000, h:44.000000 So actually that method call works.

Comment: Okay that does look right, but I imagine that's for the third cell, what happens for the other cells? You could pastebin your remaining class and I can try debug.

Comment: I've migrate the project to github, here is the link: https://github.com/gjoosen/FoodTracker

Comment: In apple's Swift project the layoutSubviews method is only called 3times

Comment: I got it to work, it might be that way you store the buttons. Use a mutable array, http://pastebin.com/vGzW417f, try my changes, excuse the UIButton casting.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Should I save all variables the way you did here?

Comment: I would say yes, use properties to store your variables.